# Is Siva ever depicted as having a childhood or adolescence?

Tags: shiva

Satapatha Brahmana has the story of his birth as an infant, sinful son of Prajapati (which is actually a metaphor for Rudra absorbing the sin of Prajapati's incest with his daughter)  but that infant is never depicted as growing up.

He is also depicted as being born from anger.

Does any scriptures describe him growing up into adulthood?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

### 1. In the Śiva-purāṇa: Pippalāda Muni.

> [Chapter 24](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226420.html) - Pippalāda incarnation of Śiva, Śatarudra-saṃhitā,
> Śivamahāpurāṇa
>
> Nandīśvara said:—
>
> 44. O great sage, after saying this the celestial voice stopped. On hearing that voice the wife of the sage was surprised for a moment.
> 45. That great chaste lady, Suvarcā, desirous of attaining the world of her husband sat down and broke open her belly with a stone.
> 46. **The foetus of the child of the great sage! of brilliant divine body, came out of her belly illuminating all the ten quarters.**
> 47. O dear, **it was the incarnation of Rudra himself born of the sage Dadhīci. He was competent to perform his divine sports. He therefore
>     manifested himself.**
> 48. to 49. On seeing her son of divine form, the beloved wife of the sage
>     Suvarcā realised in hef mind that it was the incarnation of Rudra
>     himself. The great chaste lady became delighted, bowed to him and
>     eulogised him. O great sage, that form of the child was impressed on
>     her heart.
> 49. Suvarcā of pure vision, the mother, desirous of going to her husband’s region, smilingly and lovingly spoke to her son.
>
> ...
>
> 60. After consecrating the refulgent child and the fig tree who became the father of Rudra, Viṣṇu and other gods eulogised him again.
> 61. **The delighted Brahmā named him Pippalāda.** Viṣṇu and the gods said “O lord of the gods be pleased”.
> 62. After saying this and making great jubilation, Brahmā, Viṣṇu and the gods went to their respective abodes.
> 63. Then Rudra, the great lord in the form of Pippalāda, performed a penance for a long time at the foot of the fig tree, with a desire to
>     bestow benefit on the worlds.
> 64. As Pippalāda, following the convention of the world, performed the penance, a long time passed by.
>
> English Translation by J.L. Shastri

---

### 2. In the Mahabharata: Shiva as a Child sits on Uma's Lap

This happens around - after the Tripura destruction incident. Shiva, as a child, paralysed Indra-deva's hands.

> [Section CCII](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc493190.html), Drona-vadha Parva, Drona Parva
>
> **While the triple city commenced to burn, the goddess Parvati repaired
> thither to behold the sight. She had then on her lap, a child having a
> bald head with five clumps of hair on it.** The goddess asked the
> deities as to who that child was. Sakra, through ill-feeling
> endeavoured to strike that child with his thunderbolt. **The divine lord
> Mahadeva (for the child was none other), smiling, quickly paralysed
> the arm of the enraged Sakra**. Then god Sakra, with his arm paralysed
> accompanied by all the celestials, speedily repaired to the lord
> Brahma of unfading glory.
>
> Bowing unto him with their heads, they addressed Brahma with joined
> hands and said,
>
> ’some wonderful creature, O Brahma, lying on the lap of Parvati, in
> the form of a child, was behold by us but not saluted. We have all
> been vanquished by him. We, therefore, desire to ask you as to who he
> may be. Indeed, that boy, without fighting, has with the greatest ease
> vanquished us all with Purandara at our head.'
>
> Hearing these words of theirs, Brahma. that foremost of all persons,
> acquainted with Brahma, reflected for a moment and understood that boy
> of immeasurable energy to be none else than the divine Sambhu,
>
> Addressing then, those foremost of celestials with Sakra at their
> head,
>
> **Brahma said -  'That child is the divine Hara the Lord of the entire mobile and
> immobile universe**. There is nothing superior to Mahesvara. That Being
> of immeasurable splendour who was beheld by you all with Uma, that
> divine lord, had assumed the form of a child for Uma’s sake. Let us
> all go unto him. That divine and illustrious one is the Supreme Lord
> of the world. You gods, you could not recognise that master of the
> universe.'
>
> English Translation by K.M. Ganguli

---

---

### 3. Linga Purāṇa: Shiva as a child to pacify goddess Kali

To kill the demon Dâruka (who could be only killed by a woman), goddess Kali manifested but becomes uncontrolled after slaying the demon. Then Shiva assumes the form of a crying child, whom she breastfed and later on, Shiva performs the Tandava dance to pacify the goddess completely.

> [Chapter 106,](https://archive.org/details/LingaPuranaJ.L.ShastriPart2/page/n70/mode/1up?view=theater) Part 1, of the Linga-purāṇa.
>
> आज्ञया दारुकं तस्याः पार्वत्याः परमेश्वरी । दानवं सूदयामास सूदयन्तं
> सुराधिपान् ॥ १०६.१९ ॥
>
> > 19. At the behest of Parvati, the great goddess slew the demon Diruka who used to attack and kill the chiefs among Devas.
>
> ---
>
> संरंभातिप्रसंगाद्वै तस्याः सर्वमिदं जगत् । क्रोधाग्निना च विप्रेंद्राः
> संबभूव तदातुरम् ॥ १०६.२० ॥
>
> > 20. O leading brahmins, by virtue of impetuosity, and the fire of anger, the entire universe became agitated
>
> ---
>
> भवोपि बालरूपेण श्मशाने प्रेतसंकुले । रुरोद मायया तस्याः क्रोधाग्निं
> पातुमीश्वरः ॥१०६.२१ ॥
>
> > 21. **Bhava assumed the form of a boy due to his power of Maya and stationed himself in the cremation ground full of corpses and ghosts,
> >     vara, then cried in order to quell the fire of her anger.**
>
> ---
>
> तं दृष्ट्वा बालमीशानं मायया तस्य मोहिता । उत्थाप्याघ्राय वक्षोजं स्तनं
> सा प्रददौ द्विजाः ॥१०६.२२ ॥
>
> > 22. O brahmins, **on seeing the boy, who was actually Isana the goddess was deluded by his Maya. She took him, kissed him on his head and
> >     suckled him at her breasts.**
>
> ---
>
> स्तनजेन तदा सार्धं कोपमस्याः पपौ पुनः।  क्रोधेनानेन वै बालः
> क्षेत्राणां रक्षकोऽभवत् ॥१०६.२३  ॥
>
> > 23. Along with her breast milk, the boy quaffed up her wrath also and he became the protector of the holy centres.
>
> ---
>
> मूर्तयोऽष्टौ च तस्यापि क्षेत्रपालस्य धीमतः । एवं वै तेन बालेन कृता सा
> क्रोधमूर्च्छिता ॥१०६.२४ ॥
>
> > 24. He assumed eight physical forms for his manifestation as the intelligent protector of holy centres. Thus, her excessive anger was
> >     ceased by that boy.
>
> ---
>
> कृतमस्याः प्रसादार्थं देवदेवेन तांडवम् । संध्यायां सर्वभूतेन्द्रैः
> प्रेतैः प्रीतेन शूलिना ॥ १०६.२५ ॥ पीत्वा नृत्तामृतं शंभोराकंठं
> परमेश्वरी । ननर्त सा च योगिन्यः प्रेतस्थाने यथासुखम् ॥ १०६.२६ ॥ तत्र
> सब्रह्मका देवाः सेंद्रोपेंद्राः समंततः । प्रणेमुस्तुष्टुवुः कालीं
> पुनर्देवीं च पार्वतीम् ॥ १०६.२७ ॥ एवं संक्षेपतः प्रोक्तं तांडवं शूलिनः
> प्रभोः । योगानंदेन च विभोस्तांडवं चेति चापरे ॥ १०६.२८ ॥
>
> > 25. to 28. **In order to propitiate her, the delighted trident bearing lord of Devas performed the tandava dance at dusk,** along with the
> >     ghosts and leaders of goblins. After quaffing the nectar-like dance of
> >     Siva up to the throat [i.e.alter enjoying the dance of Siva very much]
> >     Paramesvari danced in the midst of ghosts, happily along with yoginis.
> >     Devas all round, including Brahma, Indra and Vişnu, bewed to and
> >     eulogised Kall and then prayed to the goddess Parvati. Thus, the
> >     Tandava of the trident-bearing lord has been briefly mentioned to you.
> >     Others are of the opinion that the Tandava of the lord is due to the
> >     Bliss of yoga.
>
> English Translation by J.L. Shastri

Comment: not an answer.  I already spelt out what I am NOT looking for, like the Satapatha Brahmana instance.the Q is "Does any scriptures describe him growing up into adulthood?".  not downvoting because the information is interesting. @vivikta

Comment: Again, I'll say, your question body and title do not match completely then. @SK . My answer is purely based on your current title of the question. In any case, they do describe the Life of Pippalada in the next chapter in the Siva Purana, if that helps you. Beyond that, I do not think we will have a "Krishna/Rama" like a detailed account of Siva's childhood to adolescence in any text available.

Comment: Childhood has two meanings: 1 the state of being a child.

2 the period during which a person is a child.  My Satapatha Brahmana clarification shows I am not looking for meaning (1).  If misinterpreting it that way works for you - go for it @vivikta

Comment: By your interpretation he had a bullhood (vrishbha avatara), sharabhahood etc.  @vivikta .